# upload image to mongo db using node js and mutler

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have a shopping-cart project that i created with react,node js,mongo db
and using mutler libary for upload the image file
untill now i ran this project localy
it mean that i run react and node js localy and so the mongo db.
but now my project is global and also the mongo db
I upload the node js to heroku
And mongo db as global
i can store all the details of the users and the products
but i cant get the image correctly
when i ran it localy using mutler i make a destination that picture will upload will added on folder name "pictures"
the problem is now all globaly and i think it wont use this folder on the data base
so i get the details without the picture

````
const cors = require("cors");
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");

const setServerConfiguration = (app) => {
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use('/public',express.static("public"));
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(cors());
  }
  const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, "./public/images/");
    },
  
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.originalname);
    },
  });
  const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
module.exports = {setServerConfiguration, upload}

const router = require("express").Router();
const { upload } = require("../config");
const ProductModel = require("../models/Product");
const UserModel = require("../models/User");

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  await UserModel.find({}, (err, obj) => {
    ProductModel.find({}, (err, obj2) => {
      const temp = [obj, obj2];
      res.json(temp);
    });
  }).clone();
});

router.post("/add-product", upload.single("product"), async (req, res) => {
  let img = req.file.filename;
  const body = req.body.product;

  await ProductModel.create({
    name: body[0],
    price: body[1],
    category: body[2],
    picture: img,
  });
  res.json("ok");
});
router.delete("/admin", async (req, res) => {
  let body = req.body.product;
  res.send(body);
  await ProductModel.deleteOne({ name: body }, (err, obj) => {});
  res.json("ok");
});
router.post("/admin", async (req, res) => {
  let price = req.body.price;
  let productName = req.body.productName;
  const filter = { name: productName };
  const update = { price: price };
  const opts = { new: true };

  await ProductModel.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, opts);
  res.json("ok");
});

module.exports = router;

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id : false,
    name: String,
    price: Number,
    category: String,
    picture: String,
  });

const ProductModel = mongoose.model("products", ProductSchema);
module.exports = ProductModel;
```[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhJf2.jpg
````

Comment: In `/add-product` endpoint, replace `let img = req.file.filename;` with `let img = req.file;` . Try this

Comment: I forgot to tell i upload my node js project to heroku and i hear that you cant store image to mongo db and view it on heroku project its correct?

Comment: You can store the images in the MongoDB database. The data type Buffer is used for storing the images in the database form of arrays. There's _No Problem_ in viewing the images if hosted in Heroku.

Comment: Sound great ! So i just need to change the schema of product model that get data : buffer? I appreciate if you send me a guide because i saw a diffrent things

Comment: If you are looking for an alternative to Heroku, you can also run the app and a MongoDB instance on Render: https://render.com/docs/deploy-mongodb